# Attaching visual studio code to docker container (Mac)

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to attach some Python code on a docker container that I am running, on Visual studio Code. 
By following option 2 of what is described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_attaching-to-running-containers), I am not able to see the "Attach Visual Studio Code" option, when I right click on the container. I have MacOS Mojave, and the latest Visual Studio Code, as well as docker versions.

[Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLIKt.png) is a screenshot from the VSC session, when I try attaching visual studio code on the docker container. As can be seen, the option, "Attach Visual Studio Code" is not there. 
I spun the docker container by running the command

```
docker run -it pyimg bash
```

where pyimg is the docker  python image that I pulled from [Anaconda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda/).

Could you please help me with the above? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please post the actual command or actions taken. Or screenshots

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I just added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. 
In the Mac version of Visual Studio Code, "Attach Visual Studio Code" is not necessary. You just need to select "Attach Shell" while right-clicking on your container and then run the lines of the python script that you want.

Comment: Happy that your problem is solved :)